# ¿Como utilizo Masonry de forma horizontal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugin

tengo el siquiente codigo

```css
.grid{
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item{
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd){
    height: 320px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(even){
    height: 500px;
}

.grid-item .numero{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .grid{
        column-count: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">1</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">2</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">3</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">4</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">5</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">6</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">7</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">8</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">9</div></div>
        <div class="grid-item"><div class="numero">10</div></div>
</div>
```

y utilizo el plugin de Masonry q los dejo aqui tambien

> https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/jquery.masonry.min.js

esto me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven los item se van colando abajo en la primera columna y continua con la siguiente luego

como si tuviera una matriz asi:

```
1 - 4 - 7 - 9
2 - 5 - 8 - 10
3 - 6
```

y yo la quiero q los item se ubique de manera horizontal y bajen, o sea asi

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
5 - 6 - 7 - 8
9 - 10
```

que solucion me dan, por favor ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a la [documentación de Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/), verás que hay una opción que es [`horizontalOrder`](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#horizontalorder) que hace exactamente lo que quieres: coloca los elementos para que (más o menos) mantengan el orden horizontal de izquierda a derecha. (Aquí puedes ver una demo en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/EmKWdr))

[image: Masonry con orden horizontal]

Así, en tu caso en particular deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // tus opciones, por ejemplo, itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  horizontalOrder: true
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he leido y aplicado dicha opcion a mi codigo, pero me daña totalmente el diseño, los `.grid-item` se pone al 100% del `.grid`, como si no leyera el `column-count: 2;` intente solucionarlo poniendo `width:50%` pero al momento del cambiar de tamaño la ventana hace cosas no deseadas, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código JS con el que llamas a masonry?

Comment: He editado la publicacion para q le se mas facil de ayudarme y cuanto al codigo js: `$('.grid').masonry({
            percentPosition: true,
            horizontalOrder: true,
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        });`